# About bitcoind listunspent API

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info-api

For now, I've set up my own bitcoind which is running as a full node and it's downloaded all blocks.

The following is the command for launching bitcoind:
bitcoind -port=8333 -rpcport=8332 -rpcuser=xxxx -rpcpassword=xxxx -discover -txindex=1 -reindex -bind=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -datadir=~/bitcoind/

Everytime when I entered listunspent, it always returned empty result.

I am wondering that are there any ways to get all blockchain transactions data and unspent data without importing the addresses which I want to query for ?

If it's impossible, then how did the service like blockchain.info make it ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Add `-addressindex=1` `-timestampindex=1` and `-spentindex=1` when running your node.

Or better, open your datadir (`~/bitcoind/`) find `bitcoin.conf` file and add all parameters there, like this:

```
port=8333
rpcport=8332
rpcuser=xxxx
rpcpassword=xxxx
txindex=1
addressindex=1
timestampindex=1
spentindex=1
bind=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Then run your node with `-reindex`, only this time, the next times you don't need `-reindex` parameter:

`bitcoind datadir=~/bitcoind/ -reindex`